# The second derivative of $U(1/r,\theta)$ with respect to $r$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In problems related to solving the Laplace equation on a disk, I am interested in proving that if $U(r,\theta)$ satisfies the Lapalce equation on a disk then so does $U(1/r,\theta)$. I want to do this using the Laplacian in its most basic form (w.r.t this problem):
$\dfrac{\partial ^2U}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{1}{r^4}\dfrac{\partial ^2U}{\partial \theta^2}=0$

I start by trying to calculate the second derivative with respect to $r$ for $U(1/r,\theta)$. At first I calculate the first partial derivative:$$-\dfrac{1}{r^2}U_r(1/r,\theta) $$ And now I have to calculate the next higher derivative. The only problem is I am unsure how to do this. I know the chain rule will be appropriate, however I'm not sure how to lay this out formally. Can anyone offer some assistance?